# JBoss/EclipseLink - Turn on SQL Logging

Tags: logging, jboss, eclipselink

How do you set EclipseLink to log the SQL statements in JBoss?

In previous JPA deployments to Glassfish, all that was required was to add this to the persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
        <!-- log sqls executed in server.log -->
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />      
</properties>
```

but it doesn't appear to work in JBoss EAP 6.2.0GA.

EDIT

I've also tried adding the following properties as per the link in Chris' comment and also a page I found about JBoss/EclipseLink logging:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="JavaLogger" />
```

and

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger" />
```

but neither resulted in SQL being logged in server.log.  Setting to `ServerLogger` gave me these extra statements in my log file (which I don't understand):

```
08:23:17,288 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) [EL Finest]: 2014-07-29 08:23:17.288--ServerSession(1945494929)--Thread(Thread[MSC service thread 1-1,5,main])--Begin weaver class transformer processing class [my/app/datamodel/entity/OpticalReceiver].
08:23:17,288 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) [EL Finest]: 2014-07-29 08:23:17.288--ServerSession(1945494929)--Thread(Thread[MSC service thread 1-1,5,main])--Weaved persistence (PersistenceEntity) [my/app/datamodel/entity/OpticalReceiver].
08:23:17,288 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) [EL Finest]: 2014-07-29    08:23:17.288--ServerSession(1945494929)--Thread(Thread[MSC service thread 1-1,5,main])--Weaved change tracking (ChangeTracker) [my/app/datamodel/entity/OpticalReceiver].
08:23:17,288 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) [EL Finest]: 2014-07-29 08:23:17.288--ServerSession(1945494929)--Thread(Thread[MSC service thread 1-1,5,main])--Weaved fetch groups (FetchGroupTracker) [my/app/datamodel/entity/OpticalReceiver].
08:23:17,288 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) [EL Finest]: 2014-07-29 08:23:17.288--ServerSession(1945494929)--Thread(Thread[MSC service thread 1-1,5,main])--End weaver class transformer processing class [my/app/datamodel/entity/OpticalReceiver].
```

Comment: If you set the log level EclipseLink should be using the default logger as described here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging which should use system.out.  Have you checked the server.log?

Comment: Yes, I am checking server.log and there's no SQL being logged although it does log that logging in to the database was successful. See edits in question.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the DefaultLogger, as this will cause System.out to be used and will respect the eclipselink.logging.level property.  The JavaLogger and ServerLogger should be configured through their respective mechanisms rather than the eclipseLink log level property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing including this dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>  
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1.0.GA</version>  
    <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>
```

Once I added that and set this in my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="JavaLogger" />
```

I was able to get SQL logging.